# CORS not working on docker containers with Nginx

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, cors

As I am new to Node, Nest, Docker, and Ngnix I am applying CORS in the container which is not working.

My application Architecture is:

```
|-ngnix docker
|-Frontend (React) - Docker container - //Published on localhost:80
|-Backend (NestJS/GraphQL) - Docker Container - //Published on localhost:3000
|-nodeJS - Docker Container - // //I am expecting published to localhost:3004 to receive CORS
```

My Nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location /api {

        #rewrite ^/api$ /api/ permanent;
        #rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  
        #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        #add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
        #add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
        #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;

        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  
        proxy_pass http://nestbackend:3000/;
        #this is NestJS I have already implemented app.enableCors();
    }

    location /api2 {
        proxy_pass http://api2:3004/;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://frontend:3003/;
    }
}
```

My NodeJS api2 is:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
let cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(cors());

app.post("/graphql", async (req, res) =>{
    console.log("Testing CORS!!!!!!!!");
    console.log("Request = ", req);
    console.log("Resource = ", res);
    return res.status(200).json({ msg: "send to the queue!" });
});


//start server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log("server started!!"));
```

I run the localhost and invoke the backend operations, but nothing happens in the Node API2 docker container. I appreciate it if you could guide me if I am missing something.

Looking forward to getting help.

Thank You!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant client code. Also, (though unrelated to your issue), you never need to list header name `Content-Length` in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header, simply because `Content-Length` is a  [CORS-safelisted response-header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your Nginix

```
location /api2 {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    proxy_pass http://api2:3004/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Syed. I did as per your directions but it didn't work. Also, I am not getting anything i.e. console.log or any next line after the API operation is performed.

Comment: What error/msg does your frontend is showing?

Comment: Frontend and backend, both are communicating properly. the API2 (3rd container) is not receiving cors. For that, I have shared the code. No error even on ngnix container. I am expecting that  console.log("Testing CORS!!!!!!!!"); should appear in container logs.

Comment: Did you use the curl command? If curl commands works then you can be sure that there is some issue with Nginix and your NodeJS code is working fine. You can use curl -X POST http://localhost:3004/graphql   to test it.

Comment: with curl -X POST localhost/api/graphql I am getting 
{"errors":[{"message":"This operation has been blocked as a potential Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Please either specify a 'content-type' header (with a type that is not one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, text/plain) or provide a non-empty value for one of the following headers: x-apollo-operation-name, apollo-require-preflight\n","extensions":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST"}}]} but with curl -X POST localhost:3000/graphql i am getting Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 Couldn't connect to server in docker.

Comment: with # curl -X POST localhost:3004/graphql  I am getting
{"msg":"send to the queue!"}#

Comment: So this means that NodeJS API2 is working correctly. So I think the CORS issue is because of how you are configuring Nginix file

Comment: ngnix config is already shared above in the question. I appreciate it f you can have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Check my new edited answer please.

Comment: the new edit is also not working for me.